# How to access password when using multiple credentials in Jenkins Pipline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

I have the following step in my pipeline:

```
      node('linux') {
        withCredentials(
          [
            usernamePassword(
              credentialsId: 'cred1',
              passwordVariable: '1PASSWORD', usernameVariable: '1USER'
            ),
            usernamePassword(
              credentialsId: 'cred2',
              passwordVariable: '2PASSWORD', usernameVariable: '2USER'
            )
          ]
        ) {
          script {

            sh """export SUDO_PASSWORD=\$2PASSWORD
          }
        }
```

I'm trying to export the password of the credential used. I do not know ahead of time which credentials would be used (this depends on the machine that's being built on). So above, if cred1 is used I want to run `sh """export SUDO_PASSWORD=\$1PASSWORD`.

How do I get the password from when it depends on which credential is used?

Comment: Can you share your whole use case? In the case of sudo, you are using the `cred2` credentials, so you can export the `2USER` and `2PASSWORD` environment variables.

Comment: Tried to update it. I can't just export 2USER and such. If I'm using cred1 I want to be able to use 1USER otherwise if I'm using cred2 I want to use 2USER.

Comment: I not fully understand how the script is defined, I bet some quotes are missed, and I'm not sure what more missing. Based on what I can see, here is my idea: `sh """export SUDO_PASSWORD="\${2PASSWORD:-\${1PASSWORD}}";"""` In this case, if 2PASSWORD is defined (and not empty) SUDO_PASSWORD will be configured to that, otherwise 1PASSWORD will be used. But unless you paste your whole use case code, I cannot give you more hint.